# Thinking in Java 4th Edition - What is classname.this.method()

Tags: java

Reading "Thinking in Java 4th Edition" i found that example in 14th chapter:

```
public class CoffeeGenerator
implements Generator<Coffee>, Iterable<Coffee> {
  private Class[] types = { Latte.class, Mocha.class,
    Cappuccino.class, Americano.class, Breve.class, };
  private static Random rand = new Random(47);
  public CoffeeGenerator() {}
  private int size = 0;
  public CoffeeGenerator(int sz) { size = sz; } 
  public Coffee next() {
    try {
      return (Coffee)
        types[rand.nextInt(types.length)].newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
  class CoffeeIterator implements Iterator<Coffee> {
    int count = size;
    public boolean hasNext() { return count > 0; }
    public Coffee next() {
      count--;
      return CoffeeGenerator.this.next();
    }
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  };    
  public Iterator<Coffee> iterator() {
    return new CoffeeIterator();
  }
}
```

And i noticed that i never faced with that construction:

```
return CoffeeGenerator.this.next();
```

What does this mean? I know about ClassName.class.Method(), but what does this mean?

Comment: It's not explained in the book?

Comment: Didn't saw... Maybe I passed it. I'll try to find it in next 10 mins...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CoffeeGenerator.this` allows access to the outer class `CoffeeGenerator` from the inner class `CoffeeIterator`

[JLS 15.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) describes this as a *qualified this*

> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by explicitly qualifying the keyword this.

Read: [Inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe i just skipped this page in book... :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The class `CoffeeIterator` is an inner class for CoffeeGenerator,
the `CoffeeGenerator.this` is a reference to the outer's class `this`.
The inner class's object has a wrapping/outer object, this is a way
to reference that wrapping/outer object.

Answer (score 2):

`CoffeeIterator` is an *inner class*.  This means that whenever a new instance of `CoffeeIterator` is created, it must be associated with an instance (object) of the outer class, `CoffeeGenerator`.  `CoffeeGenerator.this` just means, a reference to the object of the outer class it "belongs" to.

By contrast, if `CoffeeIterator` had been declared with the `static` keyword, it would be a nested class; it could access the static members and methods of `CoffeeGenerator` (even the private ones), but it is not connected to any instance of `CoffeeGenerator`.  In that case, `CoffeeGenerator.this` would be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You need `CoffeeGenerator` to provide access to the outer class, `this` for the current object and `next()` is the method call on the object.